# error while reading a 70gb bson file from HDFS in pyspark and then indexing it to Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, hdfs, bigdata, bson

I am trying to read a data that is 70gb bson file as rdd in spark and then indexing it to elastic after some processing. While the code worked perfectly fine for a part of the data (around 20gb), when I took the entire data, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR BSONFileRecordReader: Error reading key/value from bson file on line 0: Expected size to be 1179749, not 5.
org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Expected size to be 1179749, not 5.
```

I cannot even find a similar problem on the net. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The error was with the bson file itself. I had transferred the 70gb bson file from one google server to other, during which it was corrupted. Then I transferred the tar form of the file and the code worked fine. WHy i thought of transferring the data in its original form was because, tar and untar would be slower than simply transferring the data.